# Can't write file txt on android

Tags: android, permissions, file-manager

I try to make sms log, but my device send a error message like this

```
07-18 10:11:33.956: E/One(1320): Could not write file /sdcard/log.txt (Permission denied)
```

my code to write file

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
try 
{
    BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/sdcard/log.txt"), true));
    if (root.canWrite()) 
    {
        fw.newLine();
        fw.write("----+ Monitoring SMS +----" + "\n");
        fw.write("- Pesan Masuk "+ "\n");
        fw.write(logSMS + "\n");
        fw.write("          ----+||+----" + "\n");
        fw.newLine();
        fw.close();
    } 
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("One", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
}
```

my app's manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
```

I can't find any error, please help me

Comment: i mean, i can't find error in my code,, but logcat send error message :
07-18 10:11:33.956: E/One(1320): Could not write file /sdcard/log.txt (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some devices sdcard isnt in the root directory.

What you want to do it is the replace `"/sdcard/log.txt"` with `root + "/log.txt"` you have the sdcard there but your not using it.

Comment: i found same error message : 
07-18 10:03:41.946: E/One(494): Could not write file /mnt/sdcard/sdcard/log.txt (Permission denied)
i think, it's cause directory permission, how to change directory permision direct from my code?

Comment: You are probably writing root + "/sdcard/log.txt". See what SmartLemon is suggesting.

Comment: no, i have changed to this : new File( root + "/log.txt"), but i still  find same error

Comment: Isnt it meant to be something like new File(root, location)?

Comment: I've found the problem, the problem is with the emulator, when I replace it with a new emulator, then there is no error anymore,, thank's for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to the root of the SDCard. Create a folder on your SDCard, and write into that.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

can you try replacing

```
BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/sdcard/log.txt"), true));
```

with

```
BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/log.txt"), true));
```

This is to make sure that your code is writing to a system assigned external storage path. because it varies between different devices.

Comment: I've found the problem, the problem is with the emulator, when I replace it with a new emulator, then there is no error anymore,, thank's for your answer